# How to do delete operation simultaneously from database and DataGridView

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I'm working on an app to create, delete and update records in a table, using a datagridview to show the data...

I can create and save new records from textboxes to sql table rows... But I seem to have a difficult time when it comes to updating and deleting records..

I want to know how to delete selected rows from DGV and delete them from the table too.

And update selected row, load the columns data to textboxes and be able to update and save the new values...

Please help me.. this is what it got so far..

Code for `UPDATE` button:

```
Private Sub BtnModificar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnModificar.Click
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LUISFFER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Mendez;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Invitado;Password=123456;")
        con.Open()

        'The app is in spanish, so please feel free to translate it, or write it in english

        If TxtNombre.Text = "" Then
            'Si el nombre esta vacio,
            MsgBox("No hay dato para modificar") 'There is no record to update
            'se muestra este mensaje.
            TxtCodigo.Focus()
            'Y devuelve el foco a Txtcodigo.
            Exit Sub
        End If
        BloquearTexBox(True)
        BloquearBotones(False)
        BtnGuardar.Enabled = True
        BtnCancelar.Enabled = True
        Panel2.Enabled = True
        Modificar = True
    End Using
End Sub
```

Code for the `DELETE` button:

```
Private Sub BtnEliminar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEliminar.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Esta seguro que desea eliminar este registro", "Eliminar Registro", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        Using conec As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LUISFFER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Mendez;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Invitado;Password=123456")
            conec.Open()

            Dim Comando As New SqlCommand("Delete From Alumnos Where ID=@ID", conec)

            Comando.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 10).Value = Val(TxtCodigo.Text)
            Comando.ExecuteNonQuery()


            CargarDataGrid()
            Exit Sub
        End Using
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has to do with how you set the parameters. Please try AddWithValue or replacing the `10` with your value. You are changing the value from 10 to the value of your textbox, but only after the parameter has already been added to the command.

Method 1: AddWithValue

```
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Integer.Parse(TxtCodigo.Text))
```

Method 2: Add with value in parameter

```
Comando.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, Integer.Parse(TxtCodigo.Text))
```